# Why the string won't split as read from csv using python

Tags: python, string, csv, split

Input config_note.csv:

```
Default,case 1,case 2,Time: \nJoin Connection: \nUser Remark:
```

I then only extract the last column by following command:

```
col_list = ["project", "name 1", "name 2", "note"]
df = pd.read_csv("config_note.csv", usecols=col_list, engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)
print('df["note"]:', str(df["note"].iloc[0]))
```

But the output remains as:

```
Time: \nJoin Connection: \nUser Remark:
```

I've tried to input variable directly and get what I want:

```
 test = "Time: \nJoin Connection: \nUser Remark:"
 print(test)
```

This is what I want:

```
Time:
Join Connection: 
User Remark:
```

Could anyone please help me with the input issue from csv?

Comment: what are you trying achieve by printing the string?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the string is encoded as a raw string, you can print it out into a normal string with

```py
print(df["note"].iloc[0].encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
```

so you can create a function:

```py
def decode(x):
    return x.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
print(decode(df["note"].iloc[0]))
```